# geoserver returns incorrect number of points when cql used

Tags: geoserver, layers, cql-filter

I'm using Geoserver 2.2.4 to support WMS queries. All testing is done via the "Layer Preview" page.

If I send a request with no CQL a map full of points is returned as expected.

If I add a CQL filter the map that is returned has the wrong number of points. That is, I get about 50 points on the map when the underlying SQL query (pulled from the log and executed separately) returns over 1200 points.

In both cases the same style is used. The only difference is the use of a CQL filter.

How can I get all 1200 points displayed on the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be user error. The layer information was being read from the production database while my execution of the generated SQL was against the test database. The databases were out of sync.